# Is my point inside of my (polygon) area in google code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I m actually writing a web application using google map.

In this application, I define some area (polygones) with 4 points.

If I click on the map, I need to know if the actual point clicked is in the area by a calcul.

Do you know how can I do this ? Or a mathematical way to know it ?

[image]

Thanks for advance

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/ provides a good explanation on this topic and an example implementation written in C that you can easily adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You want to load in the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry), like so:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Then you can have an event listener on the map for click events, which uses that Geometry library's `poly.containsLocation` function to check if the polygon contains the coordinates clicked:

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, yourPolygon)) {
        console.log('in polygon');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a point that you know is inside or outside the polygon, and check how many polygon lines you cross between that point and the clicked point.

If you have a known point outside the polygon (which is easy because you can pick a point that is far away), and you cross an odd number of polygon lines with a line drawn to the clicked point, then you know that the clicked point is inside the polygon.